# git subtree to add the files directly under root folder

Tags: git, git-subtree

I want to add a source repo B into a target repo A directly under the parent folder '`application`' of A by using:

```
git subtree add --prefix=application <remote name of B> <branch name of B>
```

while being at the parent folder of A.

By doing the above, the result is to create a folder 'application' under the parent folder 'application'. What I want is not to create any child folder, just to append everything under parent folder. I have tried anything like `--prefix, --prefix=./`
Nothing works. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `git subtree` does require a prefix; if `--prefix=` or `--prefix=.` does not work, it probably has to be non-empty, meaning you can't get what you want.

Comment: If you already have other files from the parent project under `application`, then the `git subtree` contrib script (not an official Git command at all) which appears to be installed on your machine, will not proceed, it wants and empty folder to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `git subtree add` does not like `-P.`, but `git subtree pull` works with it if you coerce things a bit. The idea is that you fake the initial commit structure which is usually done by `git subtree add` as follows:

Being in Repo A on your target branch with clean workding dir, assming Repo B has remote path `../repoB` (can be any fetch URL though) and source ref `main` (can be any remote ref though):

```bash
git switch -c temp
git subtree add -P temp --squash ../repoB main

git switch - # return to original branch

git switch -c init temp^2 # select squashed commit as starting point
# the following sed is probably somewhat unstable, but does the job
# the important point is to change to 'git-subtree-dir: .' within commit message body here!
patchedCommitMessage=$(git show -s --format=%B init | sed 's/temp/./')
git commit --amend --no-edit -m "$patchedCommitMessage"

git switch - # return to original branch

# using '-s ours' is beneficial if your target repoA 
# already contains potentially conflicting changes,
# you may omit this here and resolve merge conflicts 
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-edit -s ours init --no-edit

# cleanup
git branch -D init
git branch -D temp
```

After running the above commands, you've successfully updated the branch in `repoA` such that a subsequent `git subtree add -P. --squash ../repoB main` works to incorporate upstream changes!